# tus.io with Azure Functions

Tags: rest, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I want to process big files with Azure Functions using HTTP(S). I need something with resumable file upload like tus.io. Is it possible to implement an Azure Function(s) with tus.io, for example by augmenting "HTTP & webhooks".

Many thanks in advance, X.

Comment: have you found any solution for this, if any please share any reference link for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very likely to hit the [HTTP timeout limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout) of 230 seconds and instead of building and maintaining your own upload service, you could directly use [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/storage/blobs/) for it.

By generating and using a [SAS key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json), you can let clients directly upload to blob storage which is already designed for massive scale and supports resuming uploads/downloads.

Comment: how can implement resumable file upload using azure blob storage, can you share any reference links